# Unable to map array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, mapping, axios

I am fairly new to React and I have a problem with handling data from a REST API with React. I am getting Pokemon cards from a Pokemon TCG API. The data returned is JSON which contains all kinds of information about the card including an image url. I am trying to display a list of pokemon cards but I am unable to:

Because I am practicing, I do everything in the **App.js** file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pokemon: "",
      //url: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?name=",
      listOfPokeImageUrls: []
    }
  }

  lookupPokemon() {
    this.setState({
      listOfPokeImageUrls: []
    })

    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    axios.get(`https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?name=squirtle`)
      .then(response => {
        response.data.cards.forEach(element => {
          this.state.listOfPokeImageUrls.push(element.imageUrl);
        });
        //this.forceUpdate(); 
      })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.listOfPokeImageUrls);

    let imageList = this.state.listOfPokeImageUrls.map(
      (element) => { return <div><img src={element.imageUrl} alt=""></img></div> }
    );

    console.log(imageList);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text"></input>
        <button onClick={this.lookupPokemon.bind(this)}>Fetch pokemoncards</button>
          {imageList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The problem that I am facing is that the **let imageList** is always empty after mapping. Therefore the cards are not showing up on my screen. I am logging some info, first the array of image url's and secondly the array that is supposed to hold the div and img elements. When I look into the console I get the following:

[image]

Why does it not map the image's with the divs as I expect? Am I missing some basic knowledge regarding React?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the comments down below I fixed it, I forgot to use setState in the getData method:

[image]

Therefore, it wasn't working.

Comment: Array.from(source, calback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following code.

You can use map that returns image url. You can change state like this but it would not trigger react lifecycle render method for that you have to do set state.

```
getData() {
    axios.get(`https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?name=squirtle`)
      .then(response => {
        const urls = response.data.cards.map(element => {
          return element.imageUrl;
        });
        this.setState({
           listOfPokeImageUrls: urls
        });
        //this.forceUpdate(); 
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to store anything in the state of a React component you have use the setState method.
So, in your code :

```
getData() {
axios.get(`https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?name=squirtle`)
  .then(response => {
   const imageUrls = response.data.cards.map((card,index)=>{
   return card.imageUrl;
   })
   this.setState({listOfPokeImageUrls:imageUrls})
})
}
```